# Ask for input until it matches given string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want my program to append a user input to a list until a special input is given.

I have already tried it with a while loop but it didn't work that way.

```
in2 = []
while in1 != "END" :      
in1 = input("Enter: ")
in2.append(in1)
```

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate, because this question goes about a list.

Comment: It actually is...
Sorry my bad